# How do I insert data in two tables which are linked by foreign key?

Tags: mysql, key

I have two tables which are linked by foreign key as follows.

```
userdetails
-----------------------------
uid|username|password|address
-----------------------------

phonedetails
-----------------------------
pid|uid|phone1|phone2
-----------------------------
```

`uid` is the foreign key in `phonedetails` table. I want to insert `userdetails` in `userdetails` table and their corresponding phone numbers in `phonedetails` table.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedure :

```
DECLARE @uid INT
INSERT INTO dbo.userdetail
(Col1, Col2)
 VALUES (col1 value, col2 value)
 SELECT @uid =
 SCOPE_IDENTITY();
 INSERT INTO dbo.phonedetails
 (Col1,uid,col3) Values(col1 value,      @uid,col3 value)
```

Comment: how do i do it using php?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966747/how-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-within-php-code

Comment: http://www.rndblog.com/insert-into-multiple-mysql-tables-linked-by-a-foreign-key/

Answer (score 0):

You can make procedure to insert data in both tables.

Procedure will be like this...

- Insert userdetails data
- SELECT @uid=SCOPE_IDENTITY() ;  -- second step to catch
  the newly given uid of userdetail table in procedure.
- Insert phonedetails data using the @uid variable.

More details here [SQL - How to INSERT a foreign key as a value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019277/sql-how-to-insert-a-foreign-key-as-a-value-for-a-column)